# 'Licensing' tag obsolete?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

*FAQ:What kind of questions should I not ask here?
You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.*

Any question that involves licensing are pretty much answered by 'ask your lawyer' or 'closed, not related to programming/no discussion!/no clear scope'

So every question about licensing is pointless, the tags are pretty pointless (license/licensing) ?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: For reference: Op's [SE Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579858/where-to-host-a-project-that-contains-reverse-engineering-license)

Comment: Nah, I just clearly asked the wrong question, mine was really open ended, it deserved to be closed. But when I browsed the licensing tag I saw many closed ones that didn't deserve that in my opinion.

Comment: Software licensing questions are on topic at [Programmers.SE] according to their [faq](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq), but I can't speak to whether your particular question would be.

Comment: Are the tags for the entire stackexchange? Or are the tags separate for each sub-'forum'? Because if not, it would be good to clean up tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take as example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579858/where-to-host-a-project-that-contains-reverse-engineering-license, the question is not about licensing; it's about where hosting a project that contains code obtained with reverse engineering; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552779/android-application-apache-and-thesis is probably too localixed to be helpful to any future visitors, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435435/gpl-lgpl-and-mpl-what-does-it-mean is not about software but about the definition of three different software licenses.

The fact a tag is used for questions on Stack Overflow doesn't mean that all the questions using that tag are allowed; they are allowed if the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) allows them.

Looking at the questions tagged [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing), I notice there are [1,938 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing); of those, [119 are closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed:1%20%5Blicensing%5D). This means only 6% of the questions were closed. I would say it's a rather minimal percentage.

Comment: Did you look at the questions that are still not closed (but older, like page 40) but have the same 'flaws' that many other have? They just seem to be ignored.

Comment: @Nope - I don't know whether kiamlaluno looked at those, but we generally worry about old questions when they get bumped.  If you're doing maintenance, it's usually OK to do the 10 most recent and highest quality questions in a tag at a time, and let the rest stay as-is.

Comment: They aren't much better (the last 10 posts) but I get what you mean: As long as the house isn't on fire there is no need to have an extinguisher in your hand. So: case closed.